# Wayland on Kubuntu 21.10 randomly crashes

Tags: kubuntu, kde, wayland

I've upgraded to Kubuntu 21.10 from Kubuntu 21.04 and it's randomly crashing, doesn't matter whether I'm on the Nvidia graphics card or on the Intel Graphics.

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 21.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.22.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.86.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-20-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: Wayland
Processors: 12 × Intel® Core™ i9-8950HK CPU @ 2.90GHz
Memory: 31,0 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 630
```

lspci output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake LPC Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GLM [Quadro P2000 Mobile] (rev a1)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
03:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
03:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
3a:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 USB 3.1 Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
3b:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev 29)
3c:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
3d:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
```

I've switched off anything that could be graphics related like windows fading in / out when minimize / maximized, etc and it still randomly happens, the whole KDE crashes killing every single application.

I've tried switching back to X11, but X11 seems to be completely dysfunctional, only my wallpaper loads and desktop icons, but nothing else KDE related.
I'm submitting crash reports every 1-2 hours, hopefully these arrive at the right place.

In the meantime, what can I do to make my system stable again, maybe there's a known workaround?

I'm not keen to wipe the system and switch distros again

**EDIT**: I've managed to reproduce the issue, not sure if this application related or Wayland related

https://twitter.com/jvmdude/status/1454419918246531082

**EDIT2**: Some syslogs around the time things crashed

[image]

[image]

**EDIT3**: Some logs from /var/log/kern.log

[image]

Comment: I am also using wayland on ubuntu 21.1 with kde plasma desktop. When I switched to wayland mode, I found one application with high cpu (50%+) usage causing the cpu temperature to go from 40 to 70+. I uninstalled that app and it is perfectly fine so far. May be high CPU usage is causing the system to crash.

Comment: @AjayC, I've tested that now by keeping htop open and the CPU stays low. Only after the application crashed does one of the CPU cores go into 100% before other applications start crashing.

Comment: Check the system log to see if that provides some clue.

Comment: I've attached some screenshots of what I'm seeing in /var/log/syslog
Seeing lots of libpng errors, some get_icon errors, some segfaults in prior crashes ... doesn't look very useful

/var/log/kern.log shows some segfaults around the time of the last crash

Comment: Managed to fix X11, going to use X11 until the next Kubuntu update again